# cannot remove directory error

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

touch student.txt
a=0
while [ $a -lt 15 ]
do
echo "enter name"
read name
echo $name >> student.txt
a=`expr $a + 1`
done
while read line
do
mkdir $line
cd $line
echo '#!/bin/bash' >> $line.sh
echo "echo '$line'" >> $line.sh

chmod u+x $line.sh
./$line.sh
cd ..
done  <student.txt
ls
a=0
while [ $a -lt 15 ]
do
while read line
do

rm -r $line
done <student.txt

a=`expr $a + 1`
done
```

this script creates a file student.txt
then takes the input of student names from the user
and creates a file and directory of the same name.
`ls` shows that they have been created
but when deleting the directory it gives the error cannot remove 'directoryname':no such file or directory
`ls` shows that they have been deleted
why is the error showing up?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a loop around the loop which deletes the created directories. After deleting them for the first time, you try again 14 times, but this will fail, because they already are deleted.

Btw, your code has a number of issues.

- Indent it to make it mode readable.
- Use quotes around `"$line"` because even a whitespace in user input will break your script
- A duplicate user input will as well end in an error. You should better test for duplicates before

You may also consider running your code through https://www.shellcheck.net/